# Microphone detected, but only picking up noise?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

Running Windows 10, have Asus Z170 Pro mobo, Corsair Carbide 200r case.

I've been using a 3.5mm microphone, plugged into the front panel of my case. It had been working without any problems for about a year. Recently, however, the microphone has stopped picking up sound; all that's being input is a bunch of static.

First, I thought the microphone had died, so I ordered a new one. However, the same thing occurs when I plug it in - all that it records is noise. The noise is slightly different for the two microphones, though.

Next, I thought it might be the drivers (Realtek HD Audio), so I uninstalled then reinstalled the drivers. No change. Reformatted the OS drive and reinstalled Windows, then reinstalled drivers. No change either.

I also tried the rear microphone port instead of the front panel port on the case. Same noise being input.

Then I suspected the sound card, or perhaps the drivers for the onboard sound card. So I installed a PCIe card (sound blaster audigy fx), but that hasn't solved the problem either.

Neither the onboard card nor the pcie sound card have any problems when it comes to audio output.

What could possibly be the problem here? I'm going to try using a USB audio interface, and if that doesn't work, I'm going to try a standalone USB microphone... I simply don't understand why I can't get microphone input anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have formatted the drive and reinstalled system, the problem should not be related to software.

What I can think of is checking BIOS settings, disable and re-enable microphone, update bios can also be tried.

If still no help, you need to go to computer repair shop or after-sale support.

Regards